# Merge sort for an integer array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting, mergesort

I've implemented merge sort an integer array. Should I change them to more meaningful names? Overall, any further suggestions on this code? I would like to improve my coding style and to shorten the code.

```
class MergeSortAlgorithm

def sort(numbers)
if numbers.size <= 1
 return numbers
 end

 array_size   = numbers.size
half_of_size = (array_size / 2).round

left_array  = numbers.take(half_of_size)
 right_array = numbers.drop(half_of_size)

 sorted_left_array = sort(left_array)
 sorted_right_array = sort(right_array)

 merge(sorted_left_array, sorted_right_array)
  end


 def merge(left_array, right_array)
  if right_array.empty?
   return left_array 
  end

 if left_array.empty?
  return right_array 
  end

   smallest_number = if left_array.first <= right_array.first
   left_array.shift
   else
      right_array.shift
      end


    recursive = merge(left_array, right_array)


   [smallest_number].concat(recursive)
   end
      end


     merge_sort = MergeSortAlgorithm.new
     puts merge_sort.sort([4, 92, 1, 39, 19, 93, 49, 10].shuffle)
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. Please ensure that you have represented the code correctly. The indentation looks wrong. (The easiest way to post code is to paste it into the question editor, highlight it, and press Ctrl-K to mark it as a code block.)

Comment: Why don't you update your code and maybe we can continue the discussion from there, for example we could do some validation of the array, what if someone enters [-1] or ['a', :1, Object] etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you can do is to improve your code layout, I recommend you use the code style that most rubyists use:

https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide/blob/master/README.md#source-code-layout

The next best thing is to write some unit tests for your code, you can use the built in [Minitest](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/MiniTest.html) library, or you can try [Rspec](http://rspec.info/documentation/3.6/rspec-core/).
You don't need complicated tests, just some assertions to make sure the sorting is indeed done correctly, which gives you freedom to refactor.

You can also use the ruby convention and change some of your if's in one liners.

```
return numbers if numbers.size <= 1
```

Besides that, as long as the code works as expected, the names you choose are good, but depending on their taste, people will like it or not.